# Is there a way to automatically update a cell annually in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

Is there a way to update a cell automatically each year? For example, if the cell says 7, on the 31st August, it updates to 8 and so on?

Thanks

Comment: besides the answer to create a macro, if the value in cell you want updated is somehow predetermined (e.g., a calculation based on the current date), then a formula might work.

Comment: Your requirement is not accurate enough, it is recommended to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another cell that stores when it was last updated, you could run a macro on opening the spreadsheet.  The macro compares the stored date to the current one, and if your end-of-year date has passed, update your cell.